# Tool for gathering and querying for text statistics per date

Tags: sql, database, database-design, nosql, statistics

At the firm we have some kind of chat application and we want to track users` input in it.

We want to be able to get statistics like "most commonly entered texts" with an option to select time period for the statistics. It would also be nice to have an option to provide additional dimensions like users` gender and get statistic like "most commonly entered text by women in november".

Let's assume the traffic is quite heavy (1 000 000 texts / day) and queries need to be very perfomant.

What would be the best tool/database to store/query such statistics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would sugest you use a search plaltform for that such as Solr or  Elasticsearch:

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

https://www.elastic.co

After you index the data you want to query, this is stupidly fast.

Comment: Do you have any experience with elasticsearch? Would you suggest how i can achieve a stat like `most commonly entered text by women in november` using it?

Comment: Elasticsearch I worked about 5 years ago. But yes, you can achieve this pretty easy. I can show you an example of Solr (Lucene). Something like this:

`http://solr_host:9999/solr/statements/select?wt=json&indent=true&fl=gender,month,text_field&q=gender:woman+month:november&group=true&group.field=text_field`

Solr and ElasticSearch use the same engine: Lucene. To create your queries, you have tons of reference, but this one is simple: http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-query-syntax.html

To Elasticsearch I would start here:
http://www.elasticsearchtutorial.com

Comment: I suggest that beyond the queries you checkout about facets and grouping. But this tools are very powerful.